# twig: check if all included arrays in an object are empty

Tags: twig

I have a twig variable containing a number of named array objects like this:

```twig
{{ dump(trashbin) }}
```

Output:

```php
array:2 [
  "Campaign" => []
  "ClientBudget" => []
]
```

What I'm currently doing is checking if the contained arrays have a length of 0:

```twig
{% if trashbin.Campaign|length == 0 and trashbin.ClientBudget|length == 0 %}
Nothing to undelete. Trashbin empty
{% endif %}
```

In the future, any number of named arrays with names I cannot foresee may be added to that list.

How can I simplify and generalize the check if all contained arrays are empty? I want to display a special message to the user in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the logic inside your controller/model you'll have to use a `flag` for this :

```
{% set has_trash = false %}
{% for trash in trashbin if not trash is empty %}
    {% set has_trash = true %}
{% endfor %}

{% if not has_trash %}
   Nothing to delete
{% endif %}
```

[twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/rr0a33)

Answer (score 2):

```
{% if trashbin|filter(v => v is not empty) is not empty %}
```

would also have worked.